# Clear offsets spark structured streaming from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

When I test, my code is as follows.

```
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","...")
    .option("subscribe","...")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
//    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .load()
```

But when I set `.option("startingOffsets", "latest")` ,resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.
How do I make `.option("startingOffsets", "latest")` take effect?

ps:I tried deleting the checkpoint file but it didn't work

Comment: Care to elaborate on  _"but it didn't work"? What exactly didn't work? I don't understand the problem :(

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I mean, I want to delete the checkpoint file to let structured streaming read kafka data from latest , but it doesn't work when I delete the files.

Comment: But it is effective because there is a problem with the data itself

Comment: What's the _"problem with the data itself"_? Isn't that the main issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to document

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

The start point when a query is started, either "earliest" which is from the earliest offsets, "latest" which is just from the latest offsets, or a JSON string specifying a starting offset for each TopicPartition. In the JSON, -2 as an offset can be used to refer to earliest, -1 to latest.
Note: For batch queries, the latest (either implicitly or by using -1 in JSON) is not allowed. For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off. Newly discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.

> For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off. Newly discovered partitions during a query will start at the earliest

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply.When I delete the checkpoint file, it is actually valid, there is a problem with the data itself.